# Use an image instead of a menu link in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I have a menu in my page that I have created. I have a link called 'Home', and I want an image to be there for only this link. I saw many modules for Drupal 6. Is there any hook or module in Drupal 7 to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question, as I googled and found something, mixed it and carved my own way to do it.

```
function mytheme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  global $base_path;    
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  if($element['#title'] == 'Home') {
    $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    $get = '<img src="' . $base_path . drupal_get_path('theme', 'arras') . '/linkback.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="' . $element['#title'] . '" title="' . $element['#title'] . '" />';
    $output1 = l($get,$element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' .$output1    . "</li>\n";   
  } else {
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: In which page should this be pasted?

Comment: In template.php and replace mytheme with the machine name of your theme.

Comment: how to add the image?

Answer (score 1):

To tweak the answer of Hacker:

If you use [fontawesome](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome) you could use these nice icons. Then you don´t need to worry about image upload...

The code in yout tempate.php could look like this:

```
function THEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  global $base_path;    
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  if($element['#title'] == 'Home') {

$element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
$get = '<i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>';
$output1 = l($get,$element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' .$output1    . "</li>\n";   
  } else {
return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

See [The Icon library of fontawsome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) for more examples for the classname (fa fa-home fa-lg)